# Get id of custom component item with and sef-friendly urls

Tags: joomla-3.5

I am developing a component a component. When i click on a item or enter the URL like this **"index.php?view=customercenter&id=31"** i receive the id of the item with this code:

**Controller:**

```
public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false)
{
    $document       = JFactory::getDocument()->input;        
    $id = $this->input->get('id', 0, 'INT');
    $vName = $this->input->get('view', 'customercenter');
    $this->input->set('view', $vName);

    parent::display($cachable, $urlparams);

    return $this;

}
```

That works and i recieve the id "31". But when i enable sef-friendly urls and create the router.php, i always **get "0"**

**Router.php:**

```
function CustomerCenterBuildRoute( &$query ) {
$segments = array();
   if (isset($query['view']))
   {
            $segments[] = $query['view'];
            unset($query['view']);
   }
   if (isset($query['id']))
   {
            $segments[] = $query['id'];
            unset($query['id']);
   };
   return $segments; }
function CustomerCenterParseRoute($segments) {
   $vars = array();
   switch($segments[0])
   {
           case 'categories':
                   $vars['view'] = 'categories';
                   break;
           case 'category':
                   $vars['view'] = 'category';
                   $id = explode(':', $segments[1]);
                   $vars['id'] = (int) $id[0];
                   break;
           case 'article':
                   $vars['view'] = 'article';
                   $id = explode(':', $segments[1]);
                   $vars['id'] = (int) $id[0];
                   break;
   }
   return $vars;
}
```

**The link:**

```
<a href='" . JRoute::_('index.php?view=customercenter&id=' . $row->id . ':' . JFilterOutput::stringURLSafe($row->name) ) . "'>" . $row->name . "</a>
```

Does the method "input->get('id', 0, 'INT');" not work with sef-friendly urls?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found the mistake, i had to replace "article" with the right name of the view in my component "customercenter":

**Wrong:**

```
case 'article':
                   $vars['view'] = 'article';
                   $id = explode(':', $segments[1]);
                   $vars['id'] = (int) $id[0];
                   break;
```

**Correct:**

```
 case 'customercenter':
                   $vars['view'] = 'customercenter';
                   $id = explode(':', $segments[1]);
                   $vars['id'] = (int) $id[0];
                   break;
```